# Remove matching string in input value with comma

Tags: jquery, replace, match

How can I remove matching string with comma before or after

Ex :

```
<input value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10">
```

jQuery :

```
var input = $("input");
var val = input.val();
var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
var new_val = val.replace(random,"");

input.val(new_val);
```

Values not look like 1-10 (this is a example)

Problem with how can I remove comman before or after too ?

Think about if matching string has first position and last position. So it's problem

PS : I have to find by string, not index or something else

Playground : http://jsbin.com/ulikof/1/edit

Any ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If add you add the trailing comma when selecting the random number, it will remove the single comma and display correctly:

```
var input = $("input");
var val = input.val();
var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);

if(val.indexOf(random) != 0) {
  random = ',' + random;
}
else {
  random = random + ','; 
}

var new_val = val.replace(random,"");

input.val(new_val);
```

Comment: what about last string like `10` cannot replace by `10,` its not found

Comment: + `else if (val === random) {random = random}` , if just only one string left

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic way using pure JS in which you could add any amount of numbers without updating the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/zuMNf/1/

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0], // [0] or loop through inputs
    val = input.value,
    arr = val.split(','),
    len = arr.length,
    random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * len);

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(parseInt(arr[i]) == random) {
        var j = i;
    }
};

arr.splice(j, 1);

input.value = arr.join(',');
```

Comment: No , I have to find with string , not index